# Applying different border color to each mat datatable row from the set of colors

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have set of seven colors lets say `borderColor=['primary', 'accent', 'emphasis', 'warn', 'error', 'info', 'success']`. I want to give different border-left color to each row. If number of rows are more than 7 then from 8th row colors will get repeated for each row in the sequence of borderColor array.

HTML

```
 <table  mat-table="" [dataSource]="dataSource">
        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
          <th  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
          <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="basicColumns"></tr>
        <tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: basicColumns; let colorIndex = 
        index; ">
        </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked } from '@angular/core';
import {ELEMENT_DATA, ELEMENTTEST_DATA } from './../data/element-data';
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'table-styling',
  templateUrl: './table-styling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table-styling.component.scss']
})

export class TableStylingComponent  {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  borderColor = ['primary', 'accent', 'emphasis', 'warn', 'error', 'info', 'success'];
}
```

Comment: how do you get these rows? Is it dynamic from a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for the `modulo` operator combined with `ngStyle`.

```
<tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: basicColumns; let colorIndex = index;"
  [ngStyle]="{ 'border-left-color': borderColor[colorIndex % borderColor.length] }">
</tr>
```

---

**Example:**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>B</th>
  </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of rowData; let index=index"
      [ngStyle]="{ 'background-color': colors[index % colors.length] }">
    <td>{{ row.a }}</td>
    <td>{{ row.b }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
rowData = [];
  colors = ['#123456', '#654321', '#abcabc', '#666666']

  constructor() {
    for (let i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
      this.rowData.push({ a: 'A' + i, b: 'B' + i});
    }
  }
```

See stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6vlrzh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: [ngStyle]="{ 'border-left-color': borderColor[colorIndex % borderColor.length] }" this expression is not getting resolved to take value for array

Comment: I pushed an example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

Use ngClass to add Class from your borderColor array make sure all the class you add in borderColor is valid.

code:

```
<table  mat-table="" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
      <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="basicColumns"></tr>
    <tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: basicColumns; let colorIndex = 
    index; " [ngClass]="borderColor[colorIndex]">
    </tr>
```

styles.css

```
.primary {
    border-left: #ccc; // your color hex code

}
.warn{
    border-left: #000; // your color hex code
}
```

and so on...

Comment: Getting proper iterations on ngClass, but giving css property for each class may not be the feasible way, In material we have color attribute which has values which are in borderColor array. Can we find some way to link iterations with those attributes so that border color is applied to each row?

Comment: the `<tr>` tag doesn't have property called color so even if we property bind it will show error, this is one of the possible way or you can use ngStyle